# Using a C/C++ block inside a Jupyter Python notebook

Tags: jupyter, xeus-cling

I'm trying to put together a notebook showing ideas in many different languages. I'm able to do Python, Ruby, Javascript, Scala, and Java (and a few more, from BeakerX), and while I can make a C/C++ notebook (using Xeus-Cling) it's unclear to me if there's any cell magic to put a C/C++ in with all the others.

I don't need interop between the languages / data produced by blocks in different languages, although that'd be nice.

```
%%ruby
puts "Hello World"
# Hello World

%%scala
println("Hello, world")

%%xcpp # bad guess...? doesn't work
#include <stdio.h>
printf("Hello, World!");

> UsageError: Cell magic `%%xcpp` not found.
```

X-C's docs indicate that there probably isn't (existing) cell magic to do this, but I want to check that (and that there's not an alternative to X-C that already does this) before diving in and figuring out to make it happen. If there's not existing cell magic, I'd appreciate pointers to making it.

Comment: I recently discovered this project, maybe it does what you're looking for? https://github.com/xapharius/CppMagic